# How to check checkbox on load ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check input checkbox on load page and if checked our value subtract from the total value. How can I solve?

HTML

```
<p>{{vm.TOTAL VALUE}}</p>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected" ng-change="vm.checkItems(item)" ng-checked="vm.itemArray.indexOf(item.id) > -1"/></td>
    <td>{{ item.SOMEVALUE}}</td>
</tr>
```

Controller

```
vm.itemArray = [4,9,45]
vm.TOTALVALUE = "345"
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question is very unclear as currently written.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough points to comment yet, but let me see if I understand your question. Do you just want to automatically check the box for that specific id when the page loads?

```
ng-checked="vm.itemArray.indexOf(item.id) > -1
```

If you want to just have all boxes automatically checked on page load, you could just do

```
ng-checked="true"
```

I hope I understood your question properly.

Good luck!

Comment: I want to call automatically function for each item in ng-repeat which is checked

Comment: So I have pretty much your exact code and it is working great. The only thing you have that I dont have is your ng-change. Try getting rid of that and see what happens?

Comment: Or try to simplify it and see if you can get it working that way first. I have this in my controller    "$scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 45];
    $scope.itemArray = [4, 9, 45];"

Comment: And this in my template "<table>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-checked="itemArray.indexOf(item) > -1" /></td>
                <td>{{ item}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>"

Comment: Actually, let me update my answer. That might look better

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your controller with the following to see if you can get it to work.

Put the following into your controller

```
$scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 45];
$scope.itemArray = [4, 9, 45];
```

And this in your template

```
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-
checked="itemArray.indexOf(item) > -1" /></td>
            <td>{{ item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I have what you have, but without the ng-change directive on my checkbox element. If this works, let me know and I might be able to help debug whatever is happening that shouldnt be? 
Let me know!

Here is a screenshot of what I get with this code [image]

Comment: tnx josh, i need this for the calculation, in fact i have some number (456) and need first this (your explanation) and next what I need is for each checked checkbox in rows some calculation, because I have one cell in row with some price, this price need to subtracted from this number when modal is showing

Comment: No problem! Sorry I couldn't be more help!